# writing nested namespace routes on rail3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i use

```
rails g scaffold_controller admin/sub/Product name:string
```

to generate crud page,

now i need write route.rb file to map the admin_sub_product_controller,how to write this route file on rails3?

it's hard for me to write 2 level namespace mapping route

```
namespace admin do
    resource :products
end
```

this only wokrs for /admin/products,but for mapping admin/sub/proudcts how to write?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
namespace :admin do
  namespace :sub do
    resources :products
  end
end
```

rake routes

```
    admin_sub_products      GET    /admin/sub/products(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/sub/products"}
                            POST   /admin/sub/products(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/sub/products"}
    new_admin_sub_product   GET    /admin/sub/products/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/sub/products"}
    edit_admin_sub_product  GET    /admin/sub/products/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/sub/products"}
    admin_sub_product       GET    /admin/sub/products/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/sub/products"}
                            PUT    /admin/sub/products/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/sub/products"}
                            DELETE /admin/sub/products/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/sub/products"}
```