# How to redirect two different routes by single controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two same routes `resources :errors` with different url's in different folders inside the `routes.rb`.

```
Routes:
---------

namespace :enr do
  namespace :locations do #( url: enr/locations/:location_id/errors)
    resources: errors 
  end

  namespace :rds do
    resources :errors #(url: enr/rds/errors)
  end
end

controller:
------------

I have a controller for `enr/rds/errors` only.
```

how to change these two url's by `IF` condition. For example,

if location_id is nil
  i need to show this #`(url: enr/rds/errors)`
else
  I need to show `(url: enr/locations/:location_id/errors)`
end

So it will change depends upon the `location_id`. Where should i write this condition to change the url's by the `location_id`. Any Example would be more appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if location_id.nil? %>
  <%= link_to 'nil location_id', enr_locations_errors %> 
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'not nil location_id', enr_rds_errors %> 
<% end %>
```

`enr_locations_errors` and `enr_lrds_errors`  are not the only paths available.  You can use one of the seven default routes (`index`, `new`, `create`, `show`, `edit`, `update`, `destroy`) or add a custom one.  Check `rake routes` and look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4519990/643500)

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to add this code in my controller or view? Thanks