# how to change links to more SEO friendly rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, seo

I have such links in my app

`http://localhost:3000/lv/manufacturer_products?manufacturer=Komptech`

```
http://localhost:3000/en/products?category=Shredders
```

But my friend said that these links are not SEO friendly, tht I have to change them, to

```
http://localhost:3000/en/manufacturer_products/Komptech
```

or similair to this

```
http://localhost:3000/en/products/category/Shredders
```

But how can I actually change the structure off link without help off any gem ? using routes ?

Thanx

Comment: yep, you guessed it - routes

Comment: many ways add robots.txt in public folder http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation for [namespaces](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4519990/2128691) on SO.

You could even just do named routes.  something like this:

```
resources :products do
  resources :manufacturers
end
```

which for the index action of `manufacturers` would return this:

```
product_manufacturers GET    /products/:product_id/manufacturers(.:format)          manufacturers#index
```

and you could then write in routes.rb

```
match '/:id/products/:name', 
     :to => 'manufacturers#index', :as => :manufacturers
```

and when you call it

`<%= link_to @manufacturer.name, manufacturers_path({id: @manufacturer.product_id, name: @manufacturer.name}) %>`

which would render `http://localhost:3000/x/products/Komptech`

Answer (score 1):

There is a railscast by Ryan Bates for this and I always follow this,

http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

Comment: I have already used friendly_id to move from product/25 to product/Shredder 25. I need to change link to be more friendly to SEO

Answer (score 0):

I can not restrict me to share this ...Once I got an excellent help to optimize the SEO of my site

look into the link

http://complitech.net/seo-basics-high-benifit-for-ruby-on-rails-developer/

Look at the 3rd point got your answer for url

3) Improve your structure of URL

Generally in old fashion the url are unstructured and not directory wise , so make your URL are structured.

example:

www.herrybaseballcards.com/images/baseball/top-ten-baseballcards.html

so in routes

`match '/:foldername/:products/:name', 
     :to => 'products#index', :as => :products`

so ignore the Query Based URL Structures